# Adding dynamic amount of subforms to Zend_Form

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm creating my form using JS - it will have a structure of:

```
<form>
[other input fields here]

// these rows added via JS
<ul>
<li>
<input name="field[0][id]">
<input name="field[0][data]">
</li>
<li>
<input name="field[1][id]">
<input name="field[1][data]">
</li>
...
</form>
```

I want to validate `id` fields. As such, for my form, I've constructed a subform `field` which I'm adding to my form, and... I'm stumped, as, within `init()` I'm not able to know how many rows there will be.

Is there a way to add an undetermined amount of subforms (akin to declaring a `multiselect[]` as multivalued, if that makes sense), or, do I have to move the creation of subforms to `isValid()`?

---

I've went ahead with moving the functionality to `isValid()` and the results are... suprising. My code:

```
foreach($values['field'] as $index => $values)
{
    $index_form = new Zend_Form_SubForm();

    $values_form = new Zend_Form_SubForm();

    $data = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('data');

    $values_form->addElement($data);

    $index_form->addSubForm($values_form, $index);
    $this->addSubForm($index_form, "field");
}
```

POST:

```
array (size=5)
  -5 => 
    array (size=1)
      'data' => string '13' (length=2)
  -4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'data' => string '10' (length=2)
  -3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'data' => string '11' (length=2)
  -2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'data' => string '12' (length=2)
  -1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'data' => string '15' (length=2)
```

getValues():

```
array (size=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'data' => string '15' (length=2)
```

While I understand why the field names are renamed (and I can live with it) I don't understand why there's only one value in the end (even though each subform has different name).

Comment: Zend Forms are ones of the most overcomplicated for no reason elements of ZF. The biggest problems start when you want to customize some elements and relations between them. I wouldn't recommend to use them at all, because mostly at minimum, time you will spend for implementation is doubled comparing to other solutions, if not now, then for the maintenance.

Comment: Well, truth be told, I've ended up with not declaring subforms, but adding default name property on elements and overloading getValues / getErrorMessages to report errors / get values based upon that value (so - $_POST[field][0][data] becomes field_0_data for Zend, but the values / errors still reference it as $values[field][0][data]). It's **crude** and I was hoping I won't be needing to do this. The most irritating this is, that according to past versions (answers I've found for ~4 years ago) this approach (and approach of naming input fields with indexes) should work.

Comment: Are you ever calling `parent::isValid($data)` from within your child `isValid()` method?  It should be called after your loop to add the subforms.

Comment: @ski4404 - Yes, I am.